# Glob exclude directory except some subdirectories

Tags: glob

I'm trying to configure a VSCode's setting that define a list of directories to exclude from a glob pattern.

Here is the default setting: `{node_modules,doc,docs,.bundle,vendor}/**`.

I would like to be able to exclude the directory node_modules excepts the following subfolders: `animate.css` and `bootstrap`.

I tried this `{node_modules/!(animate.css|bootstrap),doc,docs,.bundle,vendor}/**` but looks like the whole node_modules directory is not excluded anymore...

Thank you for any help!